# "March up the side of the buidling"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

A movie narration goes:

> The gold crescent moon hangs from a metal brace. Behind it is a lit church steeple. Stained glass windows are faintly lit. Carved statues **march up** the side of a building. ([source](https://youtu.be/KLO04tx5N0s))

I have never heard "march up" used to describe sculptures adorning a building. The phrase seems to make some but not a whole lot of sense as I assume the sculptures are immobile and thus can't exactly "march". I can see them *line up* the side of a building. What does "march up" mean here exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[March](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/march) can mean "to stand in orderly array suggestive of marching".

The statues are evenly spaced and likely facing in the same direction.

Comment: I agree with JRodge01. I remember houses with china ducks flying up the walls of the stairs. Even if they had been plates, or framed photographs they may fancifully have been described as flying up the wall.

Answer (score 1):

JRodge01 has provided a valid definition.

This may also be a **figurative use of language** intended to create a more vivid picture.

[**Personification**](https://literarydevices.net/personification/)--often employed by associating human verbs with non-human or inanimate objects--is used to make those objects seem more vivid and alive.